# Reading in a random cell value from excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I have stored `=RANDBETWEEN(10, 20)` in my excel sheet, this formula generates random values in the excel sheet between 10 to 20. I need to read this 5 random values in my java program.

Although the function is giving out different value in my excel sheet but my java program is reading the same constant random value 5 times.. how can I read 5 different random values?

This is what I have done:

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream =
                    new FileInputStream("C://users/user/Desktop/C.xls");
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
                HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
                HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
                HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
                double a1Val = cellE1.getNumericCellValue();
                System.out.println("A1: " + a1Val);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I get is:

```
A1: 12.0
A1: 12.0
A1: 12.0
A1: 12.0
A1: 12.0
```

How can I make my program to read five different values?

Answer (score 1):

You use `i` to query the same cell (A1) five times. This value is calculated upon opening / refreshing the worksheet in Excel. Why do you think that querying the same cell in rapid succession would result in something different each time?

I'm not sure why you're relying on Excel for random numbers. Is there a reason you can't generate these in Java directly instead? For example:

```
// Assuming 20 is your max, 10 your min
Random random = new Random();
int yourRandomNumber = random.nextInt((20 - 10) + 1) + 10;
```

Comment: can you suggest the solution? how can i so that i can get different values

Comment: thnks but it will create random values directly in the program, i need to fetch random values from the excel sheet.

Comment: why do you need that? It's not like Excel is any more random than Java

Comment: @lalitkumar If you explain _why_ you're doing this, perhaps people can help. At the moment it sounds a little nuts :-)

Comment: @SeanCheshire i need it because i am creating a system, which creates reads random variables for different aptitude question. if i use java i cannot have different ranges for different questions but using excel i can do this.. like question on ages have variable ranging 10-60 while questions on interest have ranges between 1000-10000..

Comment: @Ben i need it because i am creating a system, which creates reads random variables for different aptitude question. if i use java i cannot have different ranges for different questions but using excel i can do this.. like question on ages have variable ranging 10-60 while questions on interest have ranges between 1000-10000..

Comment: @lalitkumar In that case, I would simply create your random numbers in Java itself (as shown above), and use Excel to derive your minimum and maximum integer 'seeds' (again as shown in my code example), suitable for each class of question.

Answer (score 0):

You always get *0-th* row, but 5 times in line

```
HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
```

Change `0` to `i`

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   // ...
   HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(i); 
   // ...
}
```

You will get *0-th*, *1-nd* ... *4-th* rows

Comment: thanks but this creates a null pointer exception since the random integer is present in row 0 only and there is nothing in row 1.

Comment: @lalitkumar I think you cann't re-call `RANDBETWEEN` function in Excel sheet from Java.